# How does ^# in regular expression match the empty line?

Tags: regex

I always thought in regex, ^ and # like 'verb' in must follow something,
such as ^a, line begin with a, or #a, and line end with a, But ^# to me, like # is not a 'verb' in this case, like a is a object of the verb '^'

Is there anyone can give me a better explanation about this?

Comment: Uh...what? I can't parse this, sorry. Also, are you by any chance confusing `#` and `$`?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for this site - move your question to: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @web_bod I do *not* think this is appropriate for Programmers.SE; it seems to be a question specifically about code. It may not be a very well-formed question, but Programmmers is *not* a dumping ground for questions we don't like here.

Comment: It's not a verb, just read ^ as a symbol meaning start-of-string, and # as end-of-string. Then it's logical that "start-of-string end-of-string" is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here and I'm guessing you actually want to ask why `^$` matches the empty line.

The key to understanding this is that not everything a regex matches must actually be a *character* (or characters), it can just as well be a *position* in the string. Regex tokens that match positions are called "anchors" or "assertions". They don't actually consume any text, they just make sure that the regex engine currenty is at a certain position in the string.

So, for example, `^` matches if the regex engine is currently at the start of the string. In some circumstances, depending on the current settings, it may also match at the start of the current *line*. In any case it matches *before* the first character.

Similarly, `$` matches at the end of the string (or line); more precisely, it matches before the terminating linefeed, if there is one.

Therefore, `^$` only matches if there are no characters between the start of the string/line and the end of the string/line.

Comment: Sorry for this tardy response, +1 for telling me regexp not only match character but also position in that string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under the assumption that you're confusing `#` with `$`

`^` and `$` match the literal beginning and literal end of a line.  Not the last character or first character.  And it does not require a last character or first character to work.

Why would you want this?  Well, let's say you have several long lines and you want to add text to the end of each.  You can perform a substitution searching for `$` and replacing it with "Bork Bork Bork" (if you're making an encheferizer for instance).  Or you can find the last member of a comma separated list by using `[^,]+$`

You can also use the search expression `^$` as you mentioned to match an empty line, or you can make sure that there aren't any illegal characters on a line by searching for `^[\w\d]*$` or something.